# How to refactor separate states and abstract state in UI Router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my js app I have this in config $stateProvider section via angular ui-router:

```
.state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'app/login/login.tmpl.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl as login'
})
.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/',
  views: {
      'main': { templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html' }
  }
})
.state('app.reports', {
   url: 'reports',
   views: {
     '': {templateUrl: 'app/templates/reports.tmpl.html'},
     'devices@app.reports': {
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/devices.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'DevicesCtrl as devicesCtrl'
        },
     'graphics@app.reports': {...}
      }
  })
```

In index.html I have:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main" >

     <section ui-view>
        <div ui-view="main"></div>
     </section>
  ....
  </body>
```

It works only if I have nested ui-view="main" in ui-view.

Is it correct way to work with ui-router?
In `main.html` I have header, footer and some common information for some pages.
But I have another state, 'login', in which I'll have their own templates. But in `index.html` their will be loading with `ui-view`, not `ui-view="main"`.

How can I refactor my `index.html` and js to avoid nested `ui-view` in index.html?
Or I have a correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refactor your app state like this:

```
.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html'
})
```

That should allow you to ony have the following in your index.html:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main" >

     <section ui-view>
     </section>
  ....
  </body>
```